# Add month to previous cells date For each loop

Tags: vba, excel, date

All,

I have written a little procedure which I would like a for each loop to insert the current month into the first cell "01"/MM/YY and then add one month to the date as it goes through the loop. Using the example below;

```
K1 = 01/06/2018
L1 = 01/07/2018
M1 = 01/08/2018 etc
```

The code I am using is below - The error is on the `DateAdd` line.

```
Sub test()
Dim dt As date
dt = "01/" & Application.Text(Now(), "MM/YY")
Dim i As Double
i = 1

For Each c In Range("K1:XFD1")
    If c.Value = "" Then Exit For  
 c.Value = dt
'change date to one months time
 dt = DateAdd(m, i, dt)
 i = i + 1     
Next c

End Sub
```

Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `"m"` not `m`. `m` would be a variable. `"m"` is a literal string representing the argument being "month".

```
dt = DateAdd("m", i, dt)
```

Comment: +1. Also. Option Explicit at the top of your module would have picked this up, as it would've highlighted "m" as an undeclared variable. That's why we use it :)